# run spring boot tests twice from jenkins pipeline

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to run my suite test twice,
by a jenkins pipeline. The first time with a specific value of a variable from the application.properties
and the second one with the same properties set with a different value.

Is it possible to create two stages or steps to do it and in the second one give the property to the command line set?